# How to fade in/out text in AngularJS app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS web application that flashes 3 words on the screen with 5 seconds on screen for each of them: `Hello`, `World` & `Goodbye`.

Here is my controller:

```
self.currentIndex = 0;
self.myTexts = ['Hello', 'World', 'Goodbye'];
self.currentText = self.myTexts[self.currentIndex];

var currentInterval = $interval(function() {
  self.currentText = self.myTexts[++self.currentIndex % self.myTexts.length];
}, 5000);

// Clear the interval to prevent memory leaks
$scope.$on('destroy', function() {
    $interval.cancel(currentInterval);
    currentInterval = undefined;
});
```

Here is the Angular Template:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as myCtrl">
  {{myCtrl.currentText}}
</div>
```

It works.

But now I want the text to fade in over the first of the five seconds and I want the text to fade out over the last of the five seconds. What is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could do [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)/[fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) with jQuery. You would need access to the element, so it would be simpler doing it in the linking function a directive where you have access to the element and the $scope. Because these events would start and finish outside of Angular's digest loop, you would need to run $scope.$apply to change the text.
2. You could change the opacity that you could manage within the controller. [Example](https://jsbin.com/hugobocujo/edit?html,js,output)
3. You can create two [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) one for fading in, one for fading out and go through these steps:

   1. container is hidden initially
   2. select the next text
   3. apply fade-in CSS animation
   4. wait with $timeout for the same (or a bit longer) period
   5. apply fade-out CSS animation
   6. wait with $timeout for the same (or a bit longer) period
   7. repeat from step 2

The problem with the last solution is that the animation and the text changing is handled by two different timers, one by Angular's $timeout (text changing) and one by the browser's renderer (CSS animations).

Comment: Yes. I chose option #2. :)